# Agregar datos dentro de cualquier colección que tenga en cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, firestore

Buen día, para poner en contexto mi problema, tengo una base de datos en **Cloud Firestore**, Donde tengo un formulario de restaurantes, en el cual puedo agregar restaurantes con su correspondiente nit, razón social, ubicación, y tematica (tipo de comida).
**NOTA:**
**El nombre de la colección se llama Restaurantes**

tengo otro formulario para agregar menús, pero quisiera por ejemplo que cuando busque un restaurante, tenga que estar registrado en el formulario anterior **(Colección restaurantes)** para permitir agregar el menú, es decir, por ejemplo

tengo una colección de Restaurantes

```
Restaurantes => Restaurante1
                Restaurante2, 
                Restaurante3
```

y la validación que necesito es que si existe **Restaurante1**, me permita agregar menú dentro de ese mismo restaurante, ya que con el codigo que les pongo a continuación me genera es un ID unico en mi Cloud Firestore dentro de mi colección de restaurantes, es decir me salen registrados así:

**PSDT: Disculpeme la imagen sino que intento ser preciso en lo que quiero esperando que ustedes me entiendan, muchas gracias**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CODIGO

```
public void agregar(View view){


    String nombre = txtBusqueda.getText().toString();
    String entrada = txtEntrada.getText().toString();
    String fuerte = txtFuerte.getText().toString();

        Map<String, Object> restaurantess = new HashMap<>();
        restaurantess.put("Razón social", nombre);
        restaurantess.put("Entrada", entrada);
        restaurantess.put("fuerte", fuerte);


        db.collection("restaurantes").document(nombre)
                .set(restaurantess)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void avoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(catalogo.this, "Restaurante Almacenado!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("MESSAGE", "Dato Almacenado");
                        limpiar();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w("MESSAGE", "Error adding document", e);
                    }
                });

}
```

al hacerlo de esta manera si me agrega, pero me borra los datos que creé en mi primer formulario **(Registro de restaurantes)**

Comment: En ningún momento estás indicando a qué restaurante específico va el plato, por eso te crea un nuevo objeto de motu proprio. Si quieres que ese plato vaya a `Restaurante1` tienes que indicarlo, cosa que nunca haces.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que quiero que sea dinámico, que si yo busco Restaurante1, me acceda a Restaurante1, y eso es lo que no he podido solucionar , no se como hacer esa validación y agregar datos dentro de lo que busco y encuentro

Comment: Eso no es ningún problema. Tú crearías una referencia al restaurante encontrado, por ejemplo: `restaurantes/elRestauranteQueSea`, agregas el plato a esa referencia y el mismo se crearía ahí. En ese contexto, `elRestauranteQueSea` será una referencia dinámica, que puede ser `Restaurante1`, `Restaurante2`, `RestauranteN`

Comment: Te agradezco mucho, con tu ayuda alcanzo a entender el flujo, pero no he podido acceder a cualquiera de esos elementos de mi colección

Comment: ¿Cómo intentas acceder? Muestra el código donde obtienes el nombre dinámico del restaurante y la referencia que creas partiendo de ese dato.

Comment: Te pongo el codigo como respuesta a mi pregunta ya que acá no me lo permite

Comment: No, puedes pulsar en [edit] y agregarlo en la misma pregunta, al final. El área de respuestas es para responder nada más.

Comment: Listo, ya edité el codigo con el que estoy intentando, pero te comento, ese codigo lo tengo con otros datos, que mencioné al inicio (nit, razón social, tematica ...etc), si coloco este codigo que muestro en la pregunta, no me persisten los datos, y se me cambian por los nuevos datos

Comment: Explica qué es `nombre`  en ese contexto. Como dije antes, si tú quieres guardar los datos en un documento o colección específicos, tienes que crear una referencia que apunte a ese documento o colección, cosa que no estarías haciendo correctamente y por eso tu problema.

Comment: Por otra parte, no queda claro si en cada restaurante quieres a su vez colecciones con los platos, o los quieres guardar en un mapa o en un array etc. Si te los está sobre-escribiendo es porque no estás indicando que ese nuevo plato sea agregado en una estructura que permita varios objetos. Eso no viene explicado en la pregunta, quizá porque no te has sentado a pensar tu modelo de datos ¿?

Comment: Si, si pensé en el modelo de datos, como mencioné anteriormente, deseo buscar un restaurante, y al encontrarlo poder asignarle platos, así como se ve en la imagen que compartí, que pueda agregar más datos debajo de (nit, razón social, ubicación y tematica), que se sigan abriendo campos como platos y registrarle varios platos

Comment: Lo siento, no se como me puedo hacer entender :'(

Comment: *que se sigan abriendo campos como platos y registrarle varios platos* ... Se entiende, pero, ¿bajo que tipo de datos piensas agregar esos platos, como colecciones independientes, como arrays, como map? Eso no queda claro. Comprende que Firebase es No-SQL, y cuando diseñas los datos debes pensar también en la forma en que vas a consultarlos luego. Un mal diseño en Firebase puede ser fatal a posteriori.

Comment: Los quiero agregar como colecciones independientes

Comment: Por si no los leído, te recomiendo [el apartado **Modelo de datos** en la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) para que tengas una idea más clara de cómo funciona. Esto te ayudará a diseñar tu modelo de una forma adecuada, pues creo que el problema de fondo aquí es no tener claro ese aspecto. Aunque hagas funcionar tu código, si no tienes bien diseñado el modelo, tendrás problemas tarde o temprano.

Comment: Voy a leerlo, te agradezco demasiado por tu tiempo, cualquier cosa vuelvo a añadir un comentario

Comment: Revisa esa documentación y los ejemplos. Hay varios casos parecidos a lo que quieres, para guardar datos anidados y demás y hay ejemplos de código basados en Java para acceder a las referencias.